# Storing/updating multiple rows in from same method in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table like this

```
month | rate | admin_id
0     | 1000 | 1
```

I am storing data with following method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->admin_id as $key => $val){
            $adminbillings = AdminBilling::create([
                'month' => 0,
                'rate' => $request->rate[$key],
                'admin_id' => $val,
            ]);
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

When I add a new row in the table using this method, I also want to replace the month of previous row (which is 0) with the timestamp of the new line. So the table will become

```
month        | rate | admin_id
29-08-2017   | 1000 | 1
0            | 2000 | 1
```

I can add multiple lines from single method, but here one is store and one is update, and by default update requires two arguments. But may be I am mistaken somewhere. Can you please guide me how to achieve my target?

I can access the previous row inside the method using this line:

```
$ended_at = AdminBilling::where('admin_id', $val)->where('month', 0)->get();
```

Comment: You can check whether the add query was successful or not, if yes, run the update query.

Comment: Yes, add query is successful. can you suggest me the process to update query within same method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not best solution but you will achieve your target.
To update previous record after insertion , you can do like this -

```
       $res = AdminBilling::select('id')->orderBy('id','desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->first();  //to get prev. row

       AdminBilling::where('id',$res->id)->update(['month',date()]); // to update month
```

put these lines in your store function as -

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->admin_id as $key => $val){
        $adminbillings = AdminBilling::create([
            'month' => 0,
            'rate' => $request->rate[$key],
            'admin_id' => $val,
        ]);

    $res = AdminBilling::select('id')->orderBy('id','desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->first();
    AdminBilling::where('id',$res->id)->update(['month',date()]);

  }

return redirect('/');
```

}

Hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you. I see the logic here. I tired this way, but did not work. However, this worked (I dont know how): AdminBilling::where('admin_id', $adminId)
                    ->where('month', 0)
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                    ->skip(2)->take(1)
                    ->update(['month'=> $adminbillings->created_at]);

Comment: ok.But by skip(2)->take(1) , it will return u 3rd record from desc order.

Comment: Yes that surprised me too...!! but its working. I still do not get the logic for it. I will create some similar situations later to understand how it works.

Comment: Although I have tested my solution for less than 10 rows. I am not sure what will happen if there are 100 rows. Your solution is more logical. I will find a solution around it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

When you use create method it returns the instance of your inserted row. So you can use `$adminbillings->id` if you need the access to previously insterted row.

Comment: Thank you. but I can access previously inserted row. please read the lat line of the post. I need to edit/update it.